# Spring - Parameter value did not match expected type [java.lang.Long]

Tags: java, spring

I have the following line in my `@Controller` to return results based on a string or partial string passed. The string may be numerical, in which case I parse it to a long value

```
public @ResponseBody Page<Object> searchUsers(
    @RequestParam(value = "search-string", required = false) String string) {

    List<User> results = myRepo.findByUId(Long.valueOf(searchString).longValue();
    //do stuff
}
```

My Repo Method

```
@Query("SELECT u FROM User b WHERE u.uid LIKE :id%")
List<User> findByIdStartsWith(@Param("uid") Long uid);
```

However I get the following Exception (say my parameter is "1"):

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [1%] did not match expected type [java.lang.Long (n/a)]
```

I don't think that I'm handling this parse correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: like will not work for ids... You would have to use a function to make a char from the id, then do a like on that. Also adding stuff after the parameter is also not a very good idea either...

Comment: It's actually not a true ID, but a universal one (updated my code). But thanks will try that

Comment: Why bother for the conversion? The types have to match else it will not work, further more if the type in the database isn't a text based type like will not work and you would have to cast the value.

Answer (score 6):

Hibernate is trying casting the value "1%" to target type (User.id) which is Long. This is obviously impossible. LIKE works only with strings in hibernate, you may wrap with str(u.id) but see below.

Comment: Thanks Zbynek, I know that now. Any reference on passing numbers to a LIKE clause where the column is defined as an `int`?

Comment: Actually you may try changing it to:  
SELECT u FROM User u WHERE str(u.uid) LIKE :id% . But of course performance may suffer. I'm not 100 percent sure about the construct :id%, I would pass :idString from outside.